# ColdFusion double to long conversion error

Tags: coldfusion, type-conversion

Can somebody explain to me why ColdFusion (tested on 2016,2018 and 2021) is doing a wrong double to long conversion? I know it can mess things up for fractional values, but in this example, it is clearly an integer value.
This is the code:

```
<cfoutput>
<cfset a = 69.35>
#getMetadata(a)# #a#</br>

<cfset b = a * 100>
#getMetadata(b)# #b#</br>

<cfset c = int(b)>
#getMetadata(c)# #c#</br>
</cfoutput>
```

And this is the output:

```
class coldfusion.runtime.CFDouble 69.35
class java.lang.Double 6935
class java.lang.Long 6934
```

It is "sort-of" fixable by doing this:

```
<cfset d = int(javacast("string", b))>
#getMetadata(d)# #d#</br>
```

Returning

```
class java.lang.Long 6935
```

But I'm not really satisfied by this "solution"...
Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Because ColdFusion is running on top of java, I guess this is responsible for it:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  double a = 69.35;
  double b = a * 100;
  System.out.println(b);
  long c = (int)b;
  System.out.println(c);
  long d = Math.round(b);
  System.out.println(d);
}
```

Output:

```
6934.999999999999
6934
6935
```

And most likely, ColdFusion is using int() and not round() to convert the double value to long... This is one of the "nice" side effects of a typeless programming language, which internally makes a mess of it. Makes me think of javascript ;-)

**EDIT 2:**
As Cameron pointed out, there is a difference between #b# and #b.ToString()#. The former is returning 6935, while the latter is returning 6934.999999999999. This is confusing in my opinion, but I'll keep it in the back of my head for in case I run into another strange problem with double/long values :-)

And to make it even a bit more confusion:
int(ToString(b)) is returning 6935 while int(b.ToString()) is returning 6934...

```
<cfset a = 69.35>
#getMetadata(a)# #a#</br>
<cfset b = a * 100>
#getMetadata(b)# #b#</br>
#b.toString()# #ToString(b)#</br>
```

Is returning:

```
class java.lang.String 69.35
class java.lang.Double 6935 
6934.999999999999 6935
```

So, don't assume that b.ToString() is the same as ToString(b) ...

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately just because something looks like an integer doesn't always mean it is one ;-). If you output `#b.toString()#` the result is actually `6934.999999999999`. Since `int()` *"..calculates the closest integer that is smaller than number..."* the result is correct,. Not sure why outputting just `#b#` (without the toString()) doesn't yield the same result, but ... all part of the fun of typeless language I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @SOS touches on in their comment (not sure why they did not make it an "answer"?), the issue is not the conversion. The issue is that ColdFusion is displaying `69.35 * 100` as equalling `6935`, which it isn't. And even ColdFusion doesn't really think it is.

As far as most computing languages are concerned, `69.35 * 100` is `6934.999999999999` (check on JS, Python, Ruby etc if you like), due to issues with the inherent inaccuracy of representing decimal fractional values in a system that stores stuff in binary. I've written about this before: [Floating point arithmetic with decimals](https://blog.adamcameron.me/2016/01/floating-point-arithmetic-with-decimals.html).

Internally ColdFusion is storing the result as `6934.999999999999`:

```
<cfset f = 69.35 * 100>
<cfoutput>#f.toString()#</cfoutput>
```

This yields:

```
6934.999999999999
```

So when you use `int` to take the integer portion of `6934.999999999999`, you get `6934`. *That part* is actually doing the job correctly! ;-)

Comment: I decided not to bother as they seemed to have worked out the issue already ;-) Though I have always been curious about exactly what manipulations Adobe performs when evaluating `<cfoutput>#f#</cfoutput>` to produce `6935` instead of displaying the underlying value `6934.999999999999`- and of course why. Interestingly, Lucee choose the more sane course imo, and displays the real underlying value.

Comment: Yeah it is odd. To me when outputting an expression like that, it should *just* be calling the relevant `toString` method. It's odd - and unhelpful, I think - how it's doing something else here :-/

Comment: "So when you use int to take the integer portion" yes, this I understand, but in the actual code, I was inserting the value in a database, and it seems it is internally using int(). And the confusion part was the fact that displaying the value just before the db insert, like #b#, was returning 6935, and reading the database value right after returned 6934... In my opinion, #b# should return the same as #b.toString()#. Thank you for pointing out the difference.

Comment: Well, it gets even stranger. int(ToString(b)) is returning 6935 while int(b.ToString()) is returning 6934...
Meaning ToString(b) is internally using round() and b.ToString() is using int()???

Comment: The `.toString()` call is using Java's internal `Double.toString()` method, so it's been implemented by competent ppl. The functions were written by someone @ Allaire / Macromedia, so god knows what the "thinking" was ;-)

Comment: FWIW, whatever logic CF is using, it is not int() since it *does* return fractional numbers ...in some cases. Though as Adam said, no idea what CF's "logic" is beyond that,  lol

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm kind of late to the game with this answer, but here's what I've used in the past when encountering precision issues in ColdFusion when dealing with mathematical calculations using currency.  In order to avoid precision errors, I've always wrapped my mathematical calculations with the `precisionEvaluate()` function.  Using it with your sample code

```
<cfoutput>
<cfset a = 69.35>
#getMetadata(a)# #a#</br>

<cfset b = precisionEvaluate(a * 100)>
#getMetadata(b)# #b#</br>

<cfset c = int(b)>
#getMetadata(c)# #c#</br>
</cfoutput>
```

The resultant output looks like this.  As you can see, it converts it from a Double to a BigDecimal and it avoids the precision issues.

```
class coldfusion.runtime.CFDouble 69.35
class java.math.BigDecimal 6935.00
class java.lang.Long 6935
```

You can view the results [here](https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=a0d18eca-d58c-45ac-8d91-66ac81281516/e57ffe82-0c61-4daf-b010-2068753d5e82/4c949e10-637b-49b0-93d4-6e31009a7182.cfm).